# R manipulate dataframe of dates to include 7 days prior to each date

Tags: r, date, data-manipulation

I currently have a dataframe of date, latitude and longitude which represent samples taken. Simple example below:

```
        Date Lat lon
1 1996-03-12 -33 153
2 2004-07-15 -35 160
3 2008-07-26 -28 155
```

I want to generate a table which adds the 7 days prior to each date/lat/long combination so I can then extract lead up data from some large environmental models but I can't figure out how to generate the larger table, example output for above small table would be as follows:

```
         Date Lat lon
1  1996-03-12 -33 153
2  1996-03-11 -33 153
3  1996-03-10 -33 153
4  1996-03-09 -33 153
5  1996-03-08 -33 153
6  1996-03-07 -33 153
7  1996-03-06 -33 153
8  2004-07-15 -35 160
9  2004-07-14 -35 160
10 2004-07-13 -35 160
11 2004-07-12 -35 160
12 2004-07-11 -35 160
13 2004-07-10 -35 160
14 2004-07-09 -35 160
15 2008-07-26 -28 155
16 2008-07-25 -28 155
17 2008-07-24 -28 155
18 2008-07-23 -28 155
19 2008-07-22 -28 155
20 2008-07-21 -28 155
21 2008-07-20 -28 155
```

Comment: Rather than fully enumerate the date-lat-long combinations, have a look at the lubridate package with date intervals, or fuzzy_join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this using using `tidyr::complete` is to create a sequence of dates from `date - 6` to `date` for each row.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  group_by(row = row_number()) %>%
  complete(Date = seq(Date - 6, Date, "day")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  arrange(row, desc(Date)) %>%
  fill(Lat, lon)


# A tibble: 21 x 3
#   Date         Lat   on
#   <date>     <int> <int>
# 1 1996-03-12   -33   153
# 2 1996-03-11   -33   153
# 3 1996-03-10   -33   153
# 4 1996-03-09   -33   153
# 5 1996-03-08   -33   153
# 6 1996-03-07   -33   153
# 7 1996-03-06   -33   153
# 8 2004-07-15   -35   160
# 9 2004-07-14   -35   160
#10 2004-07-13   -35   160
# … with 11 more rows
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("1996-03-12", 
"2004-07-15", "2008-07-26"), class = "factor"), Lat = c(-33L, 
-35L, -28L), lon = c(153L, 160L, 155L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak, This works perfectly. I have not come across the complete function or group_by(row = row_number()) before. It's amazingly simple.

PS. small typo in 
``` 
fill(Lat, on)
```
should be:
```
fill(Lat, lon)
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
n_days_lookback <- 7

data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$Date), function(x){
    data.frame(Date = as.Date(seq(x$Date - n_days_lookback+1, x$Date, "days"), "%Y-%m-%d"), 
               Lat = rep(x$Lat, n_days_lookback),  
               lon = rep(x$lon, n_days_lookback))
      }
    )
  ), row.names = NULL
)
```